# Why is the form not preventing submission?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a basic form that I am using as a dummy to test some JavaScript functionality.  My goal is to click the submit button and have submission paused until a javascript function is executed, then submit the form after that.  the code I currently have is below, but the submission of the form is not prevented, and the hidden field's value is never set.  can someone explain why this is happening?

**NOTE** I am aware of a jQuery method of performing the same functionality.  I am specifically trying to solve this problem without using jQuery.  If your only answer is "jQuery is better", please do not bother.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(){
  document.getElementById("hidden").value="hidden";

  var queryString = $('#decisionform').formSerialize(); 
  alert(queryString);

  document.getElementById("form").submit();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<?php
if ($_POST){
  foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value){
    echo "<b>$key</b> $value<br>";
  }
}
?>

<form action="hello.php" method="post" id="form">
<input name="first" type="text" />
<input name="second" type="text" />
<input name="third" type="text" />
<input name="hidden" type="hidden" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="test();return false;" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have an element with the id *hidden* so `document.getElementById("hidden").value="hidden";` will throw an error as you can't set properties on `undefined`. The script will stop running and never reach `return false` so the form will submit as normal.

Comment: Plus, if the point is to avoid using jQuery, `$('#decisionform').formSerialize(); ` also throws a JavaScript error.

Answer (score 1):

try `<form action="hello.php" method="post" id="form" onsubmit="test(); return false;">`

to prevent a submit, you actually need to have a `return false`, in the `onsubmit` even of the form itself

along with not having an id on the hidden field.

Comment: Admittedly I haven't tested this, but preventing the default action of clicking on a submit button should do the same thing, no?

Comment: i guess it might, but i've always had it on the onsubmit of the form, because if the form is submitted another way, your onclick wont do anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="test();return false;" />
```

use a regular button in this case because your function is performing the submit.

```
<input name="submit" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="test()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `id` attribute from your input element. Modify `<input name="hidden" type="hidden" />` to `<input name="hidden" type="hidden" id="hidden" />`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
onclick="return test()"
```

and just return false at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Add **id="hidden"** to your input, like this:

```
 <input name="hidden" type="hidden" id="hidden" />
```